# Book recommendation for learning server management and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I'm currently managing a site that I feel could be optimized and utilized to be much faster, however, I'm having difficulty finding reliable information to do it. I find the Apache documentation to be a hard read, and too technical about things I don't have a strong grasp on.

I'm just looking for a good beginner/intermediate book about server administration to learn as much as possible about Apache, as well as how to create a nice secure, robust server that doesn't crash at the first hint of unusual traffic surges.

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529949) is a good place to start, with especial reference to Chapter 6 - Security.

These [apache.org tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html) are the definitive bare-bones guide to Apache security.

[Apache Security](http://www.apachesecurity.net/) is a good follow up - probably not the best starting manual though.

[ModSecurity Handbook](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/) is a guide for a dedicated Apache module (plugin) called: `mod_security`. This is quite advanced, so perhaps something to come back to after a few weeks/months of getting to grips with Apache.

Here's a basic (and older) [walkthrough](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/securing-apache-2-step-step) by Symantec.

Comment: Thanks for the direction and taking the time to respond!